# Copssh, how to add users?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, ssh, sshd, copssh

I installed [copssh](http://www.itefix.no/i2/copssh) on Windows Vista (64-bit) here, and the installation seemed to go fine.

It requires you to explicitly add users to log in, which is fine, so I opened the COPSSH Control Panel (really just an app), went to the Users tab, clicked Add, Forward, and the "User:" popup is empty.  The "Domain:" popup has exactly one entry: my computer name.

The "Documentation" shortcut in the start menu group is broken, but I found the folder it's supposed to point to, and I only see docs for command-line tools (which I'll investigate next).

Is there something I'm missing?  Is the COPSSH Control Panel just plain broken?

Answer (score 1):

Copssh Control Panel is now updated with some fixes. You may consider to [download the latest version](http://www.itefix.no/download) and check if it solve your problems. If it is still a problem, please [visit Copssh user forum](http://www.itefix.no/i2/forum/35) and post your findings.